# Calculating totals for today in an SP2010 list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My list has a managed metadata field called FIELD1. It also has 3 columns called Price1, Price2 & Price3. I have created a Calculated column named Payment Total that adds all price fields together.
I need to be able to total up todays payment totals based on the MM Column FIELD1.
So if FIELD1 in list entry 1 equals SPAIN and its payment total is £100 and FIELD1 in list entry 2 equals SPAIN and its payment total is £100 and FILED1 in list entry 3 equals FRANCE and its total is £50 then...
SPAIN total = £200
and
FRANCE total = £50
I needs to do this on a daily basis. I hope this makes sense!
All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Modify the View -- > Then select the **Group By** column  FIELD1. also below Group By there is an option for **Totals** . For **Payment Total** column in totals section, there will be a drop down and select **Sum** in that dropdown. . Now it will give you the Total of all items in the list and also since we have group by applied , it will give total sum of each group.
You will get a view like below:

[image]

Comment: I'll give it ago. Good timing too as I was about to create a complex workflow. Thanks

Comment: Ok...my payment Total filed is a calculated field and does not appear in the TOTAL section on the create a view screen! How annoying! The only thing I can think of is to create a WF that creates a new field that is updated by this calculated field!!unless you have a better solution?

Comment: Oh that's a tragedy. You can get rid of the calculated field and make it as a normal integer field. Make the workflow do the calculation and update it.